# Why isnt my navbar expanding right?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

So here is the code for my navbar (i use Django, so the links are dynamic)
Well, my navbar doesn't expand to the end(if you use the hamburger), and i don't want to insert a fixed number because it doesn't work.

Well, i want the expanded navbar to show login.

alternatively i want to keep the login but put it to the other side.

```css
body {
  font: 14px -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.bild {
  max-height: 600;
}

.bild img {
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.username a {
  color: #000000;
}

.username a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6f737a;
}

a.logo {
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  background: url(../img/Weramemesicon2.png) 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 40px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: none !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

.top-nav {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar a:hover,
navbar a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.general-function .search {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(../img/sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 420px 120px;
  float: left;
}

.title {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 30px 0px;
}

.general-function {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.function-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.search.selected,
.search:hover {
  background: url(../img/sprite.png) 0 -30px no-repeat;
  background-size: 420px 120px;
}

.visitor-function {
  padding: 9px 10px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #bbb;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.visitor-function li {
  padding: 9px 10px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #bbb;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.user-function .btn-mute,
.visitor-function .btn-mute {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #bbb;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.user-function .btn-primary,
.visitor-function .btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media ( max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li:not (:first-child) {
    right: 90 px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom a.btn.navbar-btn.btn-sign {
    padding: 7.5px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .signin {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
  }
}

.twitter {
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  background: #3b5998 url(../img/Sprites.png) -1.4px -2px no-repeat;
  background-size: 320px 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.twitter:hover {
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  background: #3b5998 url(../img/Sprites.png) 1.4px 1.4px no-repeat;
  background-size: 320px 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.facebook {
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  background: #3b5998 url(../img/Sprites.png) -30.2px -2px no-repeat;
  background-size: 320px 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.facebook:hover {
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  background: #3b5998 url(../img/Sprites.png) -27.9px 1.4px no-repeat;
  background-size: 320px 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Testingsite </title>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar top-nav  navbar-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="logo navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Wera</a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navi" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navi">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav custom-nav">
            <li><a href="#"> Hot </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Trending </a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'posts:all' %}"> Fresh </a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'groups:all' %}"> Groups </a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="visitor-function row">
            <ul class="navbar navbar-nav custom-nav general-function navbar-right">
              <a href="#" class="search">search</a>
              <a class="btn-mute " href=" {% url 'accounts:login' %} ">Login</a>
              <a class="btn-primary " href=" {% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Sign up</a>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.visitor-function {
    height: auto;
}
}
```